# How can I create a gedit plugin using python?

Tags: pygobject, gedit, gedit-plugin

I wanted to create a simple gedit plugin that could save the current file when mouse leaves the text area (just like the `<<leave>>` event in tkinter) using python3. I went through wiki but I couldn't get much from it (All I could do was to create a plugin that just showed in plugins menu,nothing more). Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Python plugin HOWTO](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo):

> The gedit window based on `Gtk.Window`.

Looking at the [documentation for Gtk.Window](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Window.html), it inherits from `Gtk.Widget`.

Looking at the [signals documentation for `Gtk.Widget`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#gtk-widget-signals), it looks like [`leave-notify-event`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.signals.leave_notify_event) is what you are looking for.